# Passing URL query string to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to pass a query string from the URL to a Javascript function, but it nothing I do seems to work.  I am using PHP to generate the Javascript code.

If I have the following URL:

> www.testing.com/?test=5

I want the function to output the following code:

```
"googletag.pubads().setTargeting("test","5");', 'close');"
```

I tried adding PHP code, using `echo $_GET["test"]`, but instead of displaying the value, it displays `$_GET["test"]`.  I even tried making a custom function in Javascript that picks up the URL query string, and when I try to display it, it just outputs the variable name, but not the value itself.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and have ideas how to fix this problem?

Below is the function:

```
function google_admanager_dfp_add_js($js = NULL, $type = 'slot') {
    static $ga_js = array();

    // add the js to a type
    if (isset($js) && isset($type)) {
        $ga_js[$type][] = $js;

        //add the init and service scripts the first time this is run
        if (!isset($ga_js['service'])) {

            if (variable_get('google_admanager_dfp_useasync', FALSE)) {
                google_admanager_dfp_add_js("var googletag = googletag || {};googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];", 'service');
                google_admanager_dfp_add_js("(function() {var gads = document.createElement('script');gads.async = true;gads.type = 'text/javascript';var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);})();", 'service');

                google_admanager_dfp_add_js("googletag.cmd.push(function() {", 'pre');
                google_admanager_dfp_add_js("googletag.enableServices(); });", 'close');

            } else {
                google_admanager_dfp_add_js('(function() {var useSSL = \'https:\' == document.location.protocol;var src = (useSSL ? \'https:\' : \'http:\') +\'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js\';document.write(\'<scr\' + \'ipt src="\' + src + \'"></scr\' + \'ipt>\');})();', 'service');

                // set the close script to fetch the ads.

                if (isset($_GET["test"])) {

                    // Line in question is below ->
                    google_admanager_dfp_add_js('googletag.pubads().setTargeting("test","");', 'close');
                }
                google_admanager_dfp_add_js('googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();googletag.enableServices();', 'close');
            }

        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the pair using location.search, like this:

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var pair = query.split("=");

// ...
// Line in question is below ->
google_admanager_dfp_add_js('googletag.pubads().setTargeting('+pair[0]+','+pair[1]+');', 'close');
```

`pair[0]` will be `test` and `pair[1]` will be `5`.

Comment: When I add your code, I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' for this line:             google_admanager_dfp_add_js('googletag.pubads().setTargeting('+pair[0]+','+pair[1]+');', 'close');

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/

Helped me do just what you're looking for in a simple .js file.

credit to Mathias Bank who created it.

Comment: Hmm.. I was hoping to do this in straight javascript or PHP so I wouldn't have to have another js library or file...